# Determining adaptor identifier with Managed DirectX

Tags: multiple-monitors, managed-directx

Creating a new Managed DirectX device on a single monitor setup is easy, I call the device constructor with adapter identifier 0 ( or Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter).

On a multiple monitor setup I want to create the device with the correct adapter identifier 0 or 1, depending on the primary or secondary monitor being currently used.  How can I determine which adapter id I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't figure out how to do this with Managed DirectX, wrote a wrapper for [MonitorFromWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145072%28VS.85%29.aspx) and MonitorFromPoint to do it.